# How can i solve some questions in a hashmap module?

Tags: python, hashmap

I'm doing an exercise from a programming book.
I've writen a code but some steps i can't understand.

This code i've created is a module called `hashmap`:

```
def new(num_buckets=256):
    """Initializes a Map with the given number of buckets."""
    aMap = []
    for i in range(0, num_buckets):
        aMap.append([])
    return aMap

def hash_key(aMap, key):
    """Given a key this will create a number and then convert it to
    an index for the aMap's buckets."""
    return hash(key) % len(aMap)

def get_bucket(aMap, key):
    """Given a key, find the bucket where it would go."""
    bucket_id = hash_key(aMap, key)
    return aMap[bucket_id]

def get_slot(aMap, key, default=None):
    """
    Returns the index, key, and value of a slot found in a bucket.
    Returns -1, key, and default (None if not set) when not found.
    """
    bucket = get_bucket(aMap, key)

    for i, kv in enumerate(bucket):
        k, v = kv
        if key == k:
            return i, k, v

    return -1, key, default

def get(aMap, key, default=None):
    """Gets the value in a bucket for the given key, or the default."""
    i, k, v = get_slot(aMap, key, default=default)
    return v

def set(aMap, key, value):
    """Sets the key to the value, replacing any existing value."""
    bucket = get_bucket(aMap, key)
    i, k, v = get_slot(aMap, key)

    if i >= 0:
        # the key exists, replace it
        bucket[i] = (key, value)
    else:
        # the key does not, append to create it
        bucket.append((key, value))

def delete(aMap, key):
    """Deletes the given key from the Map."""
    bucket = get_bucket(aMap, key)

    for i in xrange(len(bucket)):
        k, v = bucket[i]
        if key == k:
            del bucket[i]
            break

def list(aMap):
    """Prints out what's in the Map."""
    for bucket in aMap:
        if bucket:
            for k, v in bucket:
                print k, v
```

**1)** Why there is a keyword as a parameter in the function `new(num_buckets=256)`?
What if i set `num_buckets` as a variable and `256` as a value in the middle of the function? Does it matter where to set it?

```
def new():
    """Initializes a Map with the given number of buckets."""
    aMap = []
    num_buckets = 256              # <--- this line
    for i in range(0, num_buckets):
        aMap.append([])
    return aMap
```

**2)** Why the size of the `aMap` is `256`? Is it on purpose or just an accidental number?

**3)** What's the sense of `hash_key(aMap, key)` function?
This way doesn't guarantee that the key will be in the bucket with a "remainder-index".

> For example.

```
aMap = [[(9, 'nine')], [(10, 'ten')], [11, 'eleven']]
```

After running the function `hash_key`, the "remainder-index" will be `1`. But key `10` isn't in the first bucket.

*I'm new in Python. I hope for your help.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. It's just a default parameter. It's bound once when the code executes and allows the function's user to not set it explicitly. If you set it in your code the user has to set it when calling the function.
2. 256 is just a number. It may fit in memory nicely so that's why it was picked. I remember `Java` uses 2^n sizes for `HashMap`'s backing buckets as well but don't take my word for it.
3. I don't really understand your example. You use the hash key when inserting into and when retrieving from the map - just to get the right bucket. You then compare as you would to a list (since the buckets are actually lists).

Comment: Thanks. I've understood 1) and 2). What does i mean in 3)? There is an operation in the hash function hash() % len(aMap). What if 10 % 3 == 1 as in my example? But 10 is not in the 1 bucket.

Comment: this can not happen in this implementation. If the map's buckets-count grows you have to re-hash everything. Bere the map **starts** with 256 buckets. That's why your example is unclear.

Answer (score 0):

(1) & (2)
This is an optional input parameter, a guess at an appropriate number of buckets for general use.  If "new" is called with no argument, then num_buckets will be 256.  If an argument is supplied, then num_buckets will take on that value.

(3) I think you may have a little confusion about hashing.  The purpose of a hash function is to provide an integer that encodes the key.  The hash values should spread the set of keys throughout the given integer range.  For example, "nine" might map to 12; "ten" might map to 301.  The latter would be converted to 45 (301 % 256).

According to the data you presented, "ten" will map to key 10, not 1.  Can you explain how you got 1 for the remainder-index?

Comment: I got 1 after 10 % 3 (3- size of map in the example, 10 - key after hashing).